# How to split a list?

Tags: python, list, split, indexing, indices

I'm getting  a list such as

```
StudentStatus = ['Physics Pass', 'Chem Distinction', 'Maths Average']
```

I am printing it like:

```
for each in StudentStatus:
    print each
```

Hence the output is

```
Physics Pass
Chem Distinction
Maths Average
```

I want to print it the other way.
I tried -

```
for each in StudentStatus:
    print each[0], each[1]
```

which just printed

```
Physics
Chem
Maths
```

How to split the list to get proper output?

Comment: I'd expect it to print `P h` and `C h` and `M a`. What *other way* did you want it printed, exactly?

Comment: In other words, what, exactly, is the *proper output* here?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Just want to see if I can access Physics and Pass separately.

Comment: So you want to split on whitespace?

Comment: What is meant by "Print in the other way"? Please show expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the last word is the grade, then you can use `str.rpartition`:

```
StudentStatus = ['Physics Pass', 'Chem Distinction', 'Maths Average']

for item in StudentStatus:
    print 'Subject: {0} - Grade: {2}'.format(*item.rpartition(' '))
```

Output:

```
Subject: Physics - Grade: Pass
Subject: Chem - Grade: Distinction
Subject: Maths - Grade: Average
```

Answer (score 0):

```
StudentStatus = ['Physics Pass', 'Chem Distinction', 'Maths Average']
for echo in StudentStatus:
    first, second = echo.split()
    print first, second
```